# For each Loop Deployment issue

Tags: service, deployment, ssis, integration

I have a package that need to use for each loop. 
I have a staging table that has all the months, I want to loop through every month (Jan, Feb, Mar, ..., Dec) and load the data into the real table.

So I have use execute SQL task to query all the column names of the staging table, and save it to "ListMonth" (type:Object). 
Then I loop through each column name by ADO Enumerator - and here the problem appear: I can loop through column name in "SSIS", but when I deploy it to Integration service, it keeps raising the errors: "Variable User::ListMonth" does  not contain a valid data object.

Does anyone know the solution to the problem?

The "ListMonth" variable already has type Object, I do not know why the problem still occurs.
I have already tried to make a script task to initialize an array of Month and loop through that by setting For each loop variable enumerator, but it raise the error that the "ListMonth" is null and it does not contain enumerator object

Please note that when running them in VS 2019 I do not have problem. The problem only occurs when I deploy the package to the SSMS Integration Service.

Comment: I _think_ that if the query returns a NULL value and/or an empty set, you can get that behaviour. If it's the case that the recordset is empty/has a null, then I'd look to make sure the connection manager is using the correct server and the account connecting has all the required permissions. The other thing to check is whether *any* package (Hello world level) works on this server from the project. It could be that something got fouled up during the deployment and it's only manifesting as the Foreach enumerator having an issue